# Shifting a graphics Path object over

Tags: java, android, path, matrix

In Java, Android specifically, how do I transform a Path object over 100 pixels? Like in C#, I would use the following code to do this:

```
// Create a path and add and ellipse.
GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();
myPath.AddEllipse(0, 0, 100, 200);

// Draw the starting position to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, myPath);

// Move the ellipse 100 points to the right.
Matrix translateMatrix = new Matrix();
translateMatrix.Translate(100, 0);
myPath.Transform(translateMatrix);

// Draw the transformed ellipse to the screen.
e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), myPath);
```

How do I do this in Android? I already have my Path object:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint pnt = new Paint();
    Path p = new Path();    

    pnt.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    pnt.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    p.moveTo(97.4f, 87.6f);
    p.lineTo(97.4f, 3.8f);

    p.lineTo(-1.2f, 1.2f);
    p.lineTo(-0.4f,-0.4f);

    p.lineTo(-0.4f,87f);

    p.lineTo(97.4f, 87.6f);
    p.close();          

    canvas.drawPath(p, pnt);            
}
```

What do you I need to do in order to shift my Path object over 100 pixels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's almost the same:

```
Matrix translateMatrix = new Matrix();
translateMatrix.setTranslate(100,0);
p.transform(translateMatrix);
```

I didn't test it, just looked into API.

Answer (score 6):

I think [`Path.offset(float dx, float dy)`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#offset%28float,%20float%29) is what you're looking for.