# Two parallel paths from one path

Tags: java, android, path

I have a path object in Java Android representing road, and I'd like to create two paths from it, as two traffic lanes (so each would be moved from the source path little bit), like this
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dziY.png]

When I use just some offset, it doesn't work. How could it be done?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Do you need actual "Paths" that fit this or do you just need to draw them at the offset?

Comment: How do you create the path and apply the offset? Do you apply the offset to the original points (starting, ending, control points) used to create the path, or do you only apply the offset to where the path is drawn?

Comment: u use canvas for drawing?

Comment: Actually here's the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023304/shifting-a-graphics-path-object-over